# should I assign a variable or return variable from getText() promise of Element in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, promise, protractor

I have a use case where I should get the webElement text using a promise then I need to extract some portion of the string for further execution.

Should the top or bottom example be used?

```js
var id = element(by.binding('smsDetails.message')).getText().then(function(message){
    var messageArray = msg.split("\n");
    var indexPosition = messageArray[0].indexOf("ID");
    id = messageArray[0].substr(indexPosition + 5, 10); 
    return id;
});
```

```js
var id;
element(by.binding('smsDetails.message')).getText().then(function(message){
    var messageArray = msg.split("\n");
    var indexPosition = messageArray[0].indexOf("ID");
    id = messageArray[0].substr(indexPosition + 5, 10); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the value (string) that `getText()` function returns. So your second method is appropriate to do that.

> But caveat to this method is that, since u dont know when protractor
>   returns the string value as its a promise, so make sure you wait until you get the text
>   value first and then perform operation on it as necessary.

Here's how -

```
var id;
element(by.binding('smsDetails.message')).getText().then(function(message){
    var messageArray = msg.split("\n");
    var indexPosition = messageArray[0].indexOf("ID");
    id = messageArray[0].substr(indexPosition + 5, 10);

    //Ideal place to perform operation on text value - id

}).then(function(){

    //Perform operation on text value - id

});
//DONT perform operation on text value - id
```

If you still need to use the value outside the promise (`.then()`), then wait until the text is returned and then continue with your operation -

```
var id = '';
browser.wait(function(){
    return element(by.binding('smsDetails.message')).getText().then(function(message){
        //Other operations
        id = messageArray[0].substr(indexPosition + 5, 10);
        return !!message;
    });
}).then(function(){
    //Perform operation on text value - id
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why u are using brwoser.wait for hold of a value for further

Comment: @Vivek i have mentioned a comment there, where in if you want to use the id value outside the promise that getText() returns, then you should wait for it. There are many ways to wait and i have shown one of them. If you don't wait until promise is returned, then you cannot perform operation on `id` outside the promise. Thanks

Comment: there are many - check https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

Comment: @Vivek check http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if it solved your problem

Comment: Ok girish, problem is not solved here. When i used brwoser.wait and use id further in the code , it is showing undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105765/discussion-between-girish-sortur-and-vivek).

Comment: @Vivek i have updated the answer to resolve the undefined error. Let me know if it still doesn't work. Thanks